# Image not displayed using CSS in Grails 3.2.8

Tags: css, grails

I am trying to add logo to the page and failed to load the image to the page 
   for some reason.

**test.css:(/assets/stylesheets)**

```
 .logo {
 background-image: url("../images/testimage.png") ;
 width:124px;
 height:95px;
 float:left;
 margin:0 0 0 0;}
```

**index.gsp:(/grails-apps/views)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>Welcome to Grails</title>
</head>
<body> <div class="logo"></div></body>
</html>
```

**testimage.png (/assets/images/testimage.png)**

Its just a small thing and its not working.

Thanks
Pooja

Comment: do you really have your gsps under `/assets`?

Comment: yes. its under /assets/views/index.gsp

Comment: the gsps should be actually under `/grails-app/views`

Comment: Sorry. my Mistake. gsp is under /grails-app/views/index.gsp

Comment: your code looks fine. perhaps you don't include your css into the gsp... clean your browsers cache etc.

Comment: I did clean the browser cache, application clean, etc. Still not working

Comment: are other images shown?

Answer (score 0):

Add test.css to `\grails-app\assets\stylesheets\application.css` like:

```
*= require test
```

Comment: Did this help you?